# Azure Function Fixed Delay Retry locking up function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have been testing out the FixedDelayRetry mechanism of Azure Functions but I am running into an scenario where the function wont process the next message until the function consumes all of the remaining retries and the message ends up in the deadletter queue.

I am using .NetCore 3.1 and the Functions SDK 3.0

This is a very boiled down version of my function where I am able to reproduce the issue

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
[FixedDelayRetry(5, "00:01:00")]
public void Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("SomeTopic", "SomeSubscription", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] string item,
    ExecutionContext context,
    ILogger log
)
{
    log.LogInformation($"Function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

    throw new System.Exception("Error Happened!!");
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
throw new System.Exception("Error Happened!!");
```

***You are throwing the exception in the code execution so that you're seeing this behavior like***

> A scenario where the function won't process the next message until the function consumes all of the remaining retries and the message ends up in the dead letter queue.

***To not encounter the retries, throw the exception in the `catch` block***.

**Function Code**:

```
[FunctionName("FixedDelayRetryTest")]  
[FixedDelayRetry(5, "00:01:00")]  
public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("Topic", "Subscription", Connection = "ServiceBusConnString")] string item, ExecutionContext context, ILogger log)  
{  
    try  
    {  log.LogInformation($"Function executed at {DateTime.Now}");  }
    catch  
    {  throw new System.Exception("Error Happened!!");  }
}
```